# Dynamically summing varying location and size 2d arrays of a large dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

This is my first Python program but I'm not new to programming. I'm concerned I may not be taking the best approach to my problem.  I have hundreds of csv files that I read into a pandas data frame.  The data frame is x  rows by 24 columns, parsed.  What I need to do is sum specific sections of the data frame, for instance in a 10 x 10 frame I would write
**df.iloc[0:4, 0:4].values.sum()** while also summing
**df.iloc[5:9, 0:4].values.sum()**

At this point I would change the second sum to move 1 field to the right and sum, **df.iloc[5:9, 1:5].values.sum()**.  This would continue until the last column of data was summed.  The values for the iloc would then drop a row and continue stepping over and down until the last of the data is summed, **df.iloc[6:10, 6:10].value.sum()**.

The next step is to increase the size of the second sum to
**df.iloc[5:9, 0:5].value.sum()** and so on...

The code I have sort of works but is not indexing correctly.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
from pandas import DataFrame

path = r'C:\Users\dave\Desktop\Python\CSV_files'
filenames = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
ucol = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8,9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27]

sf = []
df = []
big_df = []
for filename in filenames:
    sf.append(filename [73:-4])
    df.append(pd.read_csv(filename, header=None, usecols=ucol, skiprows=30, nrows=24))
    
big_df = pd.concat(df, ignore_index=True)
c1, c1_plus,r1, r1_plus, c2, c2_plus, r2, r2_plus,c1_adder = [0,4,0,4,0,0,0,0,1]

for r1 in range(len(big_df.index)):
    for c1 in range(len(big_df.columns)):
        c2_plus = 4
        r2_plus = r1_plus + 5
        for r2 in range((r1_plus + 1), ((len(big_df.index)) - (r2_plus - r2))):
            for c2 in range(len(big_df.columns) - c2_plus):
                print r1, r1_plus, c1, c1_plus, big_df.iloc[r1:r1_plus, c1:c1_plus].values.sum(), r2, r2_plus, c2, c2_plus, big_df.iloc[r2:r2_plus, c2:c2_plus].values.sum()
                c2_plus =  c2_plus + 1
            c2 = 0
            r2_plus = r2_plus + 1
        r2 = 0
        c1_plus = c1_plus + 1
    c1 = 0
    r1_plus = r1_plus + 1
    c1_plus = c1 + 4
r1_plus = 0
```

The output looks like this:

```
r1  r1_+    c1  c1_+    sum r2  r2_+    c2  c2_+    sum
0   4   0   4   85  5   9   0   4   1049
0   4   0   4   85  5   9   1   5   1294
0   4   0   4   85  5   9   2   6   1265
0   4   0   4   85  5   9   3   7   1297
0   4   0   4   85  5   9   4   8   1259
0   4   0   4   85  5   9   5   9   1349
0   4   0   4   85  5   9   6   10  1723
0   4   0   4   85  5   9   7   11  1838
0   4   0   4   85  5   9   8   12  1904
0   4   0   4   85  5   9   9   13  1833
0   4   0   4   85  5   9   10  14  1805
0   4   0   4   85  5   9   11  15  1751
0   4   0   4   85  5   9   12  16  1640
0   4   0   4   85  5   9   13  17  1550
0   4   0   4   85  5   9   14  18  1176
0   4   0   4   85  5   9   15  19  1001
0   4   0   4   85  5   9   16  20  1024
0   4   0   4   85  5   9   17  21  1001
0   4   0   4   85  5   9   18  22  969
0   4   0   4   85  5   9   19  23  775
0   4   1   5   0   5   9   0   4   1049
```

If you notice the c1 loop changes from 0:4 to 1:5 before the r2 loop changes.  I am perplexed as to why this is happening and have not found anything like this in an extensive search on this site.  Later in the data, both r1 nd r2 change at the same time.

EXPLANATION OF PROBLEM WITH SOLUTION IMPLEMENTATION: 3/21/18

It doesn't seem to be the solution you have created but my implementation of your solution that is not working for me.  In the solution provided, the slice is a square and when I try to implement in a rectangle, I get the error. @DJK

Here is my modified code for the def:

```
def conv(ar,length,width):
if length > ar.shape[0] or width > ar.shape[1]:
    print 'window to large for array'
    return None
else:
    down = ar.shape[0] - length + 1 #Convolutions from top to bottom
    right = ar.shape[1] - width + 1 #Convolutions from left to right

#Create row/column indecies to slice
    #numpy.arange([start, ]stop, [step, ]dtype=None)
    a = np.arange(length)[None, :, None] + np.arange(down)[:, None, None]
    b = np.arange(right)[:, None, None] + np.arange(width)   
    rows = np.repeat(b,down,0)
    cols = np.tile(a,(right,1,1))

    #Slice array
    out = ar.values[rows, cols]
   
    return out
```

As you can see I have added a variable to pass, so the window can be rectangular.  In the example I use i and j for the window shape

```
i=5
j=7
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,4,(10,10)))
conv(df,i,j).reshape(-1,i*j).sum(1)
```

This works fine, but if I change df to an 8x10, I get the following error:

> IndexError: index 8 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 8.

**FINAL SOLUTION THAT I NEEDED THANKS TO @DJK**

Modifications to DJK's def

```
def conv(ar,length,width):
    if length > ar.shape[0] or width > ar.shape[1]:
        print 'window to large for array'
        return None
    else:
        down = ar.shape[0] - length + 1 #Convolutions from top to bottom
        right = ar.shape[1] - width + 1 #Convolutions from left to right

    #Create row/column indecies to slice
    #numpy.arange([start, ]stop, [step, ]dtype=None)
    a = np.arange(length)[None, :, None] + np.arange(down)[:, None, None]
    b = np.arange(right)[:, None, None] + np.arange(width)
    rows = np.tile(a,(right,1,1))
    cols = np.repeat(b,down,0)

    #Slice array
    out = np.sum(ar.values[rows, cols], axis=0)
  
    return out
```

Modifications to call code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
sf=[]
df=[]
df0=[]
df0 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,4,(8,10)))
for i in range(len(df0),0,-1):
    for j in range(len(df0.columns),0,-1):
        sf.append(conv(df0,i,j))

df = pd.DataFrame(sf)
df
```

Sample input and output:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
0   2   1   0   1   3   1   2   1   3   3
1   2   3   3   0   2   1   1   1   1   2
2   0   2   0   3   1   0   0   2   2   1
3   1   0   3   1   3   1   0   3   1   1
4   2   0   1   1   1   0   3   3   1   0
5   3   0   3   2   1   2   0   2   2   1
6   2   2   1   2   1   3   0   1   2   3
7   0   2   1   1   3   2   1   3   1   2

0
0    [[2, 1, 0, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3], [2, 3, 3, 0, ...
1    [[3, 1, 1, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 6], [5, 6, 3, 2, 3, ...
2    [[3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 4, 6, 7], [8, 6, 5, 3, 4, 3, ...
3    [[4, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 9], [8, 8, 6, 4, 5, 4, 5],...
```

Comment: This is a nifty solution, however, it only seems to work on square arrays.  My arrays are not always 24x24, could be 22x24 or other.  If there is a way to make indexing work with non-square arrays, I would be interested in seeing that, otherwise I am still working on a solution.
@DJK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will probably be easier to do with `numpy`, as we can use fancy indexing to create a convolving window. Note though, the code below offsets by one, moving first down the rows then across the columns.

```
def conv(ar,window):
    if window > ar.shape[0] or window > ar.shape[1]:
        print 'window to large for array'
        return None
    else:
        down = ar.shape[0] - window + 1 #Convolutions from top to bottom
        right = ar.shape[1] - window + 1 #Convolutions from left to right

        #Create row/column indecies to slice
        a = np.arange(window)[None, :, None] + np.arange(down)[:, None, None]
        b = np.arange(right)[:, None, None] + np.arange(window)   
        rows = np.tile(a,(right,1,1))
        cols = np.repeat(b,down,0)

        #Slice array
        out = ar.values[rows, cols]
        return out
```

with this function, I will create some sample data so you get the jist.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,4,(10,10)))

   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  0  0  3  1  1  2  0  2  1  2
1  2  1  1  2  3  2  3  3  0  2
2  3  0  3  2  2  2  0  3  3  1
3  1  2  1  0  2  3  2  3  2  3
4  2  1  3  3  2  0  3  2  0  0
5  3  2  2  0  2  3  0  1  1  2
6  0  3  2  2  3  3  0  0  3  2
7  2  1  3  0  0  0  2  3  0  1
8  3  2  1  3  1  1  1  1  0  3
9  1  3  0  3  3  1  1  0  2  1
```

now call the function and input your desired window

```
data = conv(df,window=5)
```

lets look at the first chunk

```
data[0]

array([[0, 0, 3, 1, 1],
       [2, 1, 1, 2, 3],
       [3, 0, 3, 2, 2],
       [1, 2, 1, 0, 2],
       [2, 1, 3, 3, 2]])
```

This mimics the top left corner of our array. If you move through the chunks (i.e. `data[1], data[2], data[3]...`) you will see each window, and can validate the accuracy of this function (for your own learning).

As for the sum, I am confused as to the format you need, do you want to sum all values inside the window? or the rows or columns?

Column sums

```
conv(df,5).sum(1)
```

Row sums

```
conv(df,5).sum(2)
```

Window sum

```
conv(df,5).reshape(-1,5**2).sum(1)
```

Comment: Can you please provide a sample rectangular dataframe, like I have in this solution that does not work? Seems to work fine for me. One Error I had in this solution is a shape parameter in the if statement, which i have updated. Be sure your window is not greater than the size of the input dataframe. This solution could easily be modified to downsize the window to the shape of the dataframe if need be.